# How would you build a dynamic height news feed (timeline view) in iOS Swift similar to FB?

Tags: ios, swift

We are using Swift + iOS9.  We want to build a news feed where some of the posts are text only, and some have actual photos.  The individual posts will vary in height.  Would you use a UITableView?  Since we're doing it in Swift using Facebook's ComponentKit isn't an option.  How would you make scrolling performant?  Currently we used a UITableView, with each cell made up of a nested set of UIStackViews.  This is resulting in a choppy scroll, probably due to height differences.  Appreciate the help, thank you.

We are doing all our views programmatically.

Comment: hey, I write a wrapper of ComponentKit for swift. https://github.com/leavez/ComponentSwift. You could have a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to let the row estimate its own height.

1. Use Auto Layout when creating your table view cells.
2. Set the table view rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
3. Set the estimatedRowHeight or implement the height estimation delegate method.

You can first create the custom table cell, then add these two lines of code in viewDidLoad()

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I believe now you can already see the changes.

And You can also refer here:

[Self-sizing Table View Cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)